# Action-angle coordinates

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, conventions, phase-space, integrals-of-motion

I'm studying [action-angle coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action-angle_coordinates#Derivation) and I've come across two distinct, yet correct, definitions for the new generalized momenta, $\text{J}_k$:

$$\text{J}_k \equiv \oint p_k dq_k $$

and

$$\text{J}_k \equiv \frac{1}{2\pi} \oint p_k dq_k .$$

I'm trying to understand how they relate.

Comment: one includes a factor of $2\pi$ and the other one does not? it is just about conventions, there is no physics behind that factor (besides the fact that it simplifies the harmonic oscillator)

Comment: Doesn't it have to do with normalization or something? I'm trying to understand why one has the factor and the other does not.

Comment: So, I can use either one for any case and I'll obtain the same frequencies, same equations of motion etc? But wouldn't the new generalized momenta, $\text{J}_k$, differ by a factor of $2\pi$ depending on which definition I used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you have the harmonic oscillator

$$
H(q, p) = \frac{p^2}{2} + \frac{q^2}{2} \tag{1}
$$

In phase space, the are enclosed by a solution of Eq. (1) is

$$
A = \pi\times\sqrt{2}\times \sqrt{2} = 2\pi
$$

For this orbit, the action is

$$
J = \frac{1}{2\pi}\oint {\rm d}q\; p = \frac{1}{2\pi}A = 1 
$$

That is the reason behind the "$2\pi$", but it is absolutely not required. The action $J$ will have the same meaning even if this factor is removed